# Finding Problematic Queries

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

The below query runs in SQL Server 2008 but it is not working in SQL Server 2012. Why?

```
SELECT TOP 20
    total_worker_time / execution_count AS Avg_CPU_Time,
    Execution_count,
    total_elapsed_time / execution_count AS AVG_Run_Time,
    total_elapsed_time,
    (SELECT
        SUBSTRING(text, statement_start_offset / 2 + 1, statement_end_offset)
    FROM sys.dm_exec_sql_text(sql_handle))
    AS Query_Text
FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats
ORDER BY Avg_CPU_Time DESC
```

Comment: It must be throwing some error.you can break your query into several part and check which particular query not working.May be permission issue in new server.

Comment: what is the error/issue you are observing?

Comment: you cannot order by `Avg_CPU_Time` as it is an alias for a calculated value, use `ORDER BY 1 DESC` instead

Comment: It **does** work in higher version (verified in SQL Server 2016). It's not an issue with tsql statement itself.

Comment: yes it does, the tag is SQL Server 2012 and it does NOT work in 2012

Answer (score 1):

**statement_end_offset** means statement_end_offset is the number of characters into the currently executing batch or stored procedure at which the currently executing statement ends.

Issue : **statement_end_offset returns -1** value sometimes at that it gives error : "Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function".

Use the below modified query which will work in any SQL Server Version :-

```
SELECT TOP 20 total_worker_time/execution_count AS [Avg CPU Time],  
SUBSTRING(st.text, (qs.statement_start_offset/2)+1,   
    ((CASE qs.statement_end_offset  
      WHEN -1 THEN DATALENGTH(st.text)  
     ELSE qs.statement_end_offset  
     END - qs.statement_start_offset)/2) + 1) AS Query_Text  
FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS qs  
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(qs.sql_handle) AS st  
ORDER BY total_worker_time/execution_count DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

The `CASE` should give you some light.

```
SELECT TOP 20
    total_worker_time / execution_count AS Avg_CPU_Time,
    Execution_count,
    total_elapsed_time / execution_count AS AVG_Run_Time,
    total_elapsed_time,
   (SELECT
        SUBSTRING(text, statement_start_offset / 2 + 1,
         ( (CASE WHEN statement_end_offset = -1 
         THEN (LEN(CONVERT(nvarchar(max),text)) * 2) 
         ELSE statement_end_offset END)  - statement_start_offset) / 2+1)
    FROM sys.dm_exec_sql_text(sql_handle) )
    AS Query_Text
FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats
ORDER BY Avg_CPU_Time DESC
```

Answer (score -1):

As i mentioned in a commet, the order by clause will not work. Please try to `APPLY`the function `sys.dm_exec_sql_text`:

```
SELECT  TOP 20
        s.total_worker_time / execution_count AS Avg_CPU_Time,
        s.execution_count,
        s.total_elapsed_time / s.execution_count AS AVG_Run_Time,
        s.total_elapsed_time,
        SUBSTRING(t.text, s.statement_start_offset / 2 + 1, s.statement_end_offset)
FROM    sys.dm_exec_query_stats s 
        OUTER APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(sql_handle) t
ORDER BY 1 DESC
```

please provide us some error text, maybe there is something wrong within `SUBSTRING` function...

Comment: [_order_by_expression_](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188385%28v=sql.110%29.aspx)
Specifies a column or expression on which to sort the query result set. A sort column can be specified as a name or **column alias**, or a nonnegative integer representing the position of the column in the select list.

Comment: once again, not in SQL Server 2012